# Print Document in Right-to-Left Layout

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I wrote this code:

```
private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    Font normalFont = new Font("B nazanin",25);
    StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("سلام", normalFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0 , format);

}

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        printPreviewDialog.Document = printDocument;
        pageSetupDialog.PageSettings = printDocument.DefaultPageSettings;
        pageSetupDialog.ShowDialog();
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSetupDialog.PageSettings;
        printPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
}
```

and it's working perfectly but the problem is that it is printing text right to left and I need to my print document right to left too. So that it isn't going to show my text because it's going to be out of my document.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The alignments properties of the `StringFormat` object have no effect if you pass a printing location rather than a bounds. You need to use an overload that takes a `Rectangle` + `StringFormat` to avoid what you have in your answer below. See the [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#overloads) and the examples there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i did this instead and its work great:

```
int widthNegetive = printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width;
e.Graphics.DrawString("متن", normalFont, Brushes.Black, widthNegetive, 0, format);
```